# how to find an executable on NixOS?

Tags: haskell-stack

On NixOS if I invoke `stack exec which` it isn't able to find the `which` binary.

```
stack exec which -- which
Executable named which not found on path: [... huge list of PATHs omitted ...]
```

what is the idiomatic way to find where an executable is located? (which is made available by a `build-tool-depends`)

Note that `which which` works, I have no idea why `stack exec which` breaks down.